# Arreglos y Listas en Django

Tags: python, array, django

Estoy tratando de crear una lista con la información de varios exámenes de laboratorio, al hacer la consulta

```
perfil = perfil_examenes.objects.filter(perfil_id=id_perfil)
```

me obtiene dos registros con dos exámenes diferentes, en el for recorro es queryset. El problema es aquí

```
examenes = [ examen_serializer(item) for item in examen ]
```

que al momento de recorre el segundo registro se sobrescribe al primer diccionario, existe alguna manera de añadir otro diccionario a la lista actualmente tengo esto:

```
[{'precio5': 0, 'grupo': 'ORINA', 'precio4': 0, 'precio3': 0, 'tipo_muestra': 'Sangre', 'precio': 130, 'precio2': 0, 'codigo': '130', 'tempo_demora': 76, 'descripcion': 'Elemental: F Q S', 'id': 130}]
```

Quisiera tener algo así:

```
[{'precio5': 0, 'grupo': 'ORINA', 'precio4': 0, 'precio3': 0, 'tipo_muestra': 'Sangre', 'precio': 130, 'precio2': 0, 'codigo': '130', 'tempo_demora': 76, 'descripcion': 'Elemental: F Q S', 'id': 130}, {'precio5':0, 'grupo':xxx, etc,etc}].
```

---

```
def encontrar_examenes(request):
   id_perfil = request.GET.get('id')
   perfil = perfil_examenes.objects.filter(perfil_id=id_perfil)
   for ex in perfil:
       examen = Examenes.objects.filter(id=ex.examen_id)
       examenes = [ examen_serializer(item) for item in examen ]
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(examenes), content_type='application/json')




def examen_serializer(examen):
    return {
        'id':examen.id,
        'codigo':examen.codigo,
        'precio':examen.precio,
        'descripcion':examen.descripcion,
        'tempo_demora': examen.tempo_demora,
        'grupo': examen.grupoExamenes.nombre,
        'precio2': examen.precio2,
        'precio3': examen.precio3,
        'precio4': examen.precio4,
        'precio5': examen.precio5,
        'tipo_muestra': examen.tipo_muestra,
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás sobreescribiendo tu variable `examenes` dentro de tu bucle `for`. Sácalo del bucle:

```
def encontrar_examenes(request):
   id_perfil = request.GET.get('id')
   perfil = perfil_examenes.objects.filter(perfil_id=id_perfil)
   examenes = []
   for ex in perfil:
       examen = Examenes.objects.filter(id=ex.examen_id)
       examenes.extend([ examen_serializer(item) for item in examen ])
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(examenes), content_type='application/json')
```

Observa que estoy usando el método `extend()` para extender la lista `examenes` en  cada una de las iteraciones.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, agradezco tu ayuda Cesar.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es que examen = Examenes.objects.filter(id=ex.examen_id) te devuelve un Queryset, pero los queryset no son ejecutados hasta que no son llamados.

Te sugiero cambiar:

```
examenes = [ examen_serializer(item) for item in examen ]
```

Por:

```
examenes = list(examen.values())
```

Y luego eliminar la función examen_serializer y devolver un JsonResponse y pasarle examenes. La devolución JsonResponse serializara los datos por ti, solo debes pasarle un diccionario, algo como {'examenes':examenes}. Recuerda que el response recibido los datos van en el objeto data, asi que recibirias examenes.data.

Algo asi:

```
def encontrar_examenes(request):
   id_perfil = request.GET.get('id')
   perfil = perfil_examenes.objects.filter(perfil_id=id_perfil)
   for ex in perfil:
       examen = Examenes.objects.filter(id=ex.examen_id)
       examenes = list(examen.values())
   return JsonResponse({'examenes':examenes})
```